# MacOS: How to mount volumes using docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile?

Tags: python, macos, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

My project's folder structure looks like:

```
+ cython_test/
    + ny/
        + nyc/
            + docker-compose.yml
            + Dockerfile
            + pigeon.py
            + data/
                + temps.txt
```

The `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  worker:
    build: .  
    volumes: 
      - ./:/opt
```

The `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine3.10

RUN sleep 5000
```

To get the container started, I do:

```
docker-compose -f "ny/nyc/docker-compose.yml" up -d --build
```

And I get the output:

```
Alexs-MacBook-Pro:cython_test alexvissup$ cd "/Users/alexvissup/Codes/cython_test"
Alexs-MacBook-Pro:cython_test alexvissup$ docker-compose -f "ny/nyc/docker-compose.yml" up -d --build
Creating network "nyc_default" with the default driver
Building worker
Step 1/2 : FROM python:3.6-alpine3.10
 ---> 92a867c54c0f
Step 2/2 : RUN sleep 5000
 ---> Running in fdeb933e6cfc
```

When I `exec` into the container I expect to go into `/opt` and see everything inside my local `nyc` folder, but it's empty.

I'm required to specify the `volumes` in the `docker-compose.yml`. Is this possible?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why use an unmodified Python docker image, instead of just using the `/usr/bin/python3` that ships with OS X?  (This setup isn't really getting any benefit out of using Docker.)

Answer (score -2):

Docker volume will be created when the containers are created and not during the build time. Your docker file is execting a sleep command for a long time, therefore the docker-compose does not create the container until the sleep functions completely finish. (I don't see why you need the sleep at all, it is not a common thing in Docker world)

The second issue that you have here is that you do not define the container command nether in the docker-compose nor in the Dockerfile. You must define one in order to keep the container running after building the docker image.

You can try to use the below command to fix the issue (You may need to install python dependencies also )

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine3.10
# RUN pip install flask -- if you need to have some dependencies
WORKDIR /opt
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "pigeon.py"]
```